# How can I reuse a property within application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, application.properties

I want to reuse a Spring property in application.properties.

For example I have the following application.properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=my_database
org.jobrunr.database.databaseName=my_database
```

How can I reuse the value (my_database) of the property (spring.data.mongodb.database) for the other property (org.jobrunr.database.databaseName) , so I only have to specify the database name at one place.

Comment: Define which one you want to use and replace the other with `${spring.data.mongodb.database}` (or vice-versa). Or specify a dedicated property (`my.databaseName`) and replace both with `${my.databaseName}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

**Such as [M.Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) said** :

```
my.database.name=my_database

spring.data.mongodb.database=${my.database.name}
org.jobrunr.database.databaseName=${my.database.name}
```

You can now use the property `${my.database.name}` wherever you need the value `my_database`.

---

Let us know how it goes! :)